# Django SSL for some pages only

Tags: django, ssl, https, session-cookies

I know there are other Q/A about that but they are too low-level.

I want to know what is the proper (secure, DRY, maintainable) way of implementing partial SSL on a django site.

I would like to have https on account pages (login, singup, ...) and "applicative pages", but keep public content pages in http.

I am open to every kind of answers, but please explain like *"use https everywhere, it has pros X, Y, Z that exceed cons A, B, C"*, or *"you have to use 2 cookies"*

If it's not a bad idea to do what I say, I'd especially like to know what to do with secure cookies on non-secure pages (knowing that I want to keep a consistent experience through my site, keeping users logged-in, etc.).

Comment: Why would you want to have SSL only on some pages? You do understand it's more work than to just have *everything* running on HTTPS?

Comment: @YuvalAdam yes but is there anything I "lose" from having content pages not in HTTP? I'd like to have point of views balancing the pros and cons.

Comment: i believe that you have to define an SSL REDIRECTION function like a middleware and use that in your settings.py ,now with your WSGI using your project settings you can definit in your apache default-ssl file in which location to use or activate https. remember that get it works you have to create a self-sign-certificate too for test mode.  the complete process is little longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you need a functionality which needs to be applied on some selected views, then using decorators is the way to go. On the other hand if you want to implement something which should be applied on all requests, then we should use a middleware.

Create a decorator which will redirect the incoming request to https.

```
#decorators.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def secure_required(view_func):
    def _wrapped_view_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request and not request.is_secure():
            request_url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.get_full_path())
            secure_url = request_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(secure_url)
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
   return _wrapped_view_func
```

In your views.py

```
from decorators import secure_required

@secure_required
def myViewFunction(request):
    ...
```

Comment: `_wrapped_view_func` gives an error return outside the function! and it gives no effect back