# Apply https only for a few views using django sslserver

Tags: django, ssl

I am using django [sslserver](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver) for enabling `https`. Now the server is working with `https` and not `http`. Is it possible to apply `https` only for a few views using `sslserver`. I came across a this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742824/django-ssl-for-some-pages-only) and tried it. But to run the server with `https` we need to run the command `python manage.py runsslserver 0.0.0.0:8000` which starts the server is with `https`. And if I just run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and use the `@secure_required` decorator as mentioned in the link for the `views` which I want to be rendered with `https`, I get the following error,

```
    You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

Is there a way I can use `sslserver` and run only a few views with `https`?

Comment: seems like sslserver library has no option for that

Comment: simply not worth the effort